# Expanding on Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> to include text values?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to follow this Besy Practices [approach](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/best-practices-tips-xamarin-uitest/) and use app query.

For example...

```
using System;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace ourapp.UITests.Pages
{
    // Aliases Func<AppQuery, appQuery> with query
    using Query = Func<AppQuery, AppQuery>;

    public class SettingsPage : BasePage
    {
        readonly Query _logoutButton;

        protected override PlatformQuery Trait => new PlatformQuery
        {
            IOS = x => x.Id("settings_title"),
            Android = x => x.Id("settings_title"),
        };

        public SettingsPage()
        {
            _logoutButton = x => x.Id("logout_button");
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            //
        }

    }
}
```

However, I'm trying to ensure that controls has certain text.

```
var result = app.Query(x => x.Id("logout_button"))
                .Where(x => x.Text.Equals("logout", 
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

But I can't seem to get the FluentQuery syntax correct...

```
            _logoutButton = x => x.Id("logout_button"),
                .Where(x => x.Text.Equals("logout", 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

`CS0103: The name 'Where' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Isn't it because you have a , insted of ) after ```x.Id("logout_button")``` ?

Comment: @uvr thanks, however there's only 1 opening bracket prior to that.

Comment: What about the comma after the closing bracket on that line?

Comment: @GuruStron don't think so ???

Comment: @Jules Try to delete it.

Comment: @GuruStron nope same error

Answer (score 0):

I guess it isn't as strict as I was hoping for and I'd really wanted to include two properties, but I guess this is a very simplistic solution.

```
        _logoutButton = x => x.Text("logout");
```

I'm not really happy to accept this, hoping something will suggest something, which will return the same object and allow two conditions.

EDIT:

Or I could use one condition and then assert, that way I know I have the correct control and it has the right text. So....

```
        protected void AssertControlHasText(Query control, string text)
        {
            var query = app.Query(control);
            var result = query?.FirstOrDefault()?.Text;

            Assert.AreEqual(text, result);
        }

        _logoutButton = x => x.Text("logout"); 

        AssertControlHasText(_logoutButton, "logout");
```